# Insert into database from java is showing as the decimal value rather than the char

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ascii, sql-insert

So I am calling an insert method as such

```
insert(updateSql.toString(), parameters);
```

One of the parameters is of char type(Either 'L' or 'R')  When I go look at whats inserted into the database it's showing the ascii equivlent decimal value of L which is 76.  When I debug it, it's also being passed as L in the java so it's something with inserting it into the SQL.  The column is of varchar type so I am not sure on going about inserting the actual char ascii value instead of the decimal ascii value like it's currently doing. This is oracle btw.

This is the method:

```
public void insertIntoTable(char leftRight<---- This one, 
            String ID, 
            Number number, 

            ){

        StringBuffer updateSql = new StringBuffer().append("     UPDATE table  ")
           .append("        SET column_name = ? " )        
           .append("      WHERE      ID  = ?  " )
           .append("      AND      Number  = ?  ");




ParameterHolder parameters = new ParameterHolder();
parameters.addParameter(leftRight); <---- This one
parameters.addParameter(id);
parameters.addParameter(number);

insert(updateSql.toString(), parameters);
```

Any information is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the SQL and the content of `parameters`?

Comment: can you add the entire function code ?

Comment: Method added, variables changed for security.

Comment: So there's no type casting being done in ParameterHolder? Also, perhaps there is a handling issue in the difference between char and String for parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use simple prepared statement? That first param is a char, so use setString()

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateSql.toString());
preparedStatement.setString(1, leftRight); // use setString for char types
preparedStatement.setString(2, id);
preparedStatement.seInt(3, number);

preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's primitive char values (like 'L' or 'R') are actually considered integer types.  You can do `char c ='R' + 5` to get 'W'.  It also means you can do `int i = 'R'` and get 82.  Not knowing what's going on inside your `insert()` I can't be sure, but I'm betting that somewhere along the way there's a char-to-int conversion.  Not knowing what `ParameterHolder` is, I'd bet it's the `parameters.addParameter(leftRight)` call itself.  I suspect you're actually calling `addParameter(int)` because there's no `addParameter(char)` or the `insert()` is doing the equivalent of `preparedStatement.setInt(c)` instead of `preparedStatement.setString(String.valueOf(c))`.